# Fetch Only The Cheapest Prices?

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate-functions

I have a table of products, there can be multiple products with the same name but with different prices, i want to display only the cheapest price of each product.

Example Of Table:

```
TABLE: Products(name,price)
---------------------------
Banana -- 1,25
Banana -- 1,10
Strawberry -- 2,43
Apple -- 1,11
Apple -- 4,12
Apple -- // Some Products Can Have the Price Column Empty!!
```

I want a MySQL query to get this:

- Banana From: $1,10
- Strawberry From: $2,43
- Apple From: $1,11

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Off the top of my head, something like

select name, min(price) from products group by name;

See this link for more info.
http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/group_by.php

Then use PHP to display the data however you wish e.g. in a table etc.

Also, you haven't said whether the price field can be NULL or not.
You also haven't said whether your name field could have mixed case like "bananas" or "Bananas" or similar.  If so then you'll probably want to call UPPER(TRIM(name)) or something like that on the name field to normalize it.

Comment: Is this ignoring the products that have no value in the price column?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
  SELECT p.name,
         MIN(REPLACE(p.price, ',', '')) AS minprice
    FROM PRODUCTS p
GROUP BY p.name
```

Storing prices as a string can cause unnecessary grief when trying to get the lowest numeric value, so I used the REPLACE function to strip the character out.  But this assumes that all values have cents associated.

The aggregate function MIN (and MAX) will return NULL if the lowest value is NULL.  If you want these to show up as zero instead:

```
  SELECT p.name,
         COALESCE(MIN(REPLACE(p.price, ',', '')), 0) AS minprice
    FROM PRODUCTS p
GROUP BY p.name
```

This is why you should not store formatting -- apply it in the presentation layer, so you can accommodate other formats.

Comment: I Think Prices Like 0,67 will be treated as 67?

Comment: @David: As long as every value has cents associated, that's fine.  IE; 1,00 would be 100...

Comment: @Matt H: [Yes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min), MIN/MAX accept strings.

Answer (score 0):

select distinct name, price from products where price <> NULL order by price desc